# File pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

### I am trying to understand what does file pointer increment means .

I have declared file pointer fp and assuming that when I use fopen for any file (say test99.txt) and try to read it then 
compiler dynamically allocate memory (  in heap ofcourse because I think internally fopen make use of malloc in order to put file in main memory)
and once file stream/data of file is put in memory then I am assuming fp contains the start address of that file stream.
Now incrementing fp by 1 (++fp) which is pointer of type FILE will increase/hop the position of fp by total size of data/stream inside that file
test99.txt. If not, and let's say incrementing fp will move fp pointer to the next character (1 byte) within the file stream then why is the below output ? ( why fp moved by 16 bytes:see the diff)
Where am I misunderstanding .

*Information : size of file is 66 bytes(8KB) . Using program on unix platform on 64 bit machine (ia64 hp server) . Compiler is of HP HP-ACC-Link. Program in C*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    fp=fopen("/home/akhils/file_dir/test99.txt","r");

    printf("Address of file is %d",  fp);
    printf("\nLet's see value of ++fp %d\n", ++fp);

    fclose(fp);   
}

Output :  Address of file is 2130569600
          Let's see value of ++fp 2130569616
```

Comment: Suggestion : use `%p` to print a pointer. cast the argument to `void *`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be incrementing `FILE*` pointers, it only points to one `FILE` structure allocated by `fopen` for you.

Answer (score 1):

`fp` is a pointer to object of type `FILE`. It doesn't refer to any data of the actual file, it contains some internal data like handles and stuff.

When you increase this pointer, it is increased by the size of the `FILE` object (it depends on implementation, 16 bytes in your example). So if it was 2130569600, it will become 2130569616. But if you try to access something by this incremented address, you will probably get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The incremental function adds a number which is the weight of the type you are using. 
For pointers, it permits you to go to the next pointer if you have a table of pointer. Otherwise, it's a bad use.
Here, it adds 16 bytes to the original address because a FILE pointer weight 16 bytes, like all pointers. Like Maxim Egorushkin said, it only **point** to the the structure allocated.
Sorry for my bad english, I hope I'll be helpfull for you.